# WebRTC question video streams sometimes don't show up unless I force it to show

Tags: javascript, socket.io, webrtc

I have a website where I try to use WebRTC https://www.camspark.com/

For some reason I must of not implemented it correctly it doesn't show the video streams 100% of the time its some kind of timing issue any lag of 1 millisecond would force it not to show the video streams.

Here is my code you could load up the javascript at https://www.camspark.com/static/camspark.js

```
var ws;

var peerConnection, localStream;  
//STUN = (Session Traversal Utilities for NAT)  
var rtc_server = {
  iceServers: [
                {urls: "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"},
                {urls: "stun:stun.services.mozilla.com"},
                {urls: "stun:stun.stunprotocol.org:3478"},
                {urls: "turn:numb.viagenie.ca", credential: "webrtc", username: "admin%40camspark.com"},
                {url: "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"},
                {url: "stun:stun.services.mozilla.com"},
                {url: "stun:stun.stunprotocol.org:3478"},
                {url: "turn:numb.viagenie.ca", credential: "webrtc", username: "admin%40camspark.com"}
  ]
}

//offer SDP = [Session Description Protocol] tells other peers what you would like
var rtc_media_constraints = {
  mandatory: {
    OfferToReceiveAudio: true,
    OfferToReceiveVideo: true
  }
};

var rtc_peer_options = {
  optional: [
              {DtlsSrtpKeyAgreement: true}, //To make Chrome and Firefox to interoperate.
  ]
}
var finishSDPVideoOfferOrAnswer = false;
var isOfferer = false;
var iceCandidates = [];
var PeerConnection = RTCPeerConnection || window.PeerConnection || window.webkitPeerConnection || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection || window.mozRTCPeerConnection;
var IceCandidate = RTCIceCandidate || window.mozRTCIceCandidate || window.RTCIceCandidate;
var SessionDescription = RTCSessionDescription || window.mozRTCSessionDescription || window.RTCSessionDescription;
var getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia;
        
function hasSupportForVideoChat() {
   return window.RTCPeerConnection && window.RTCIceCandidate && window.RTCSessionDescription && navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia && (RTCPeerConnection.prototype.addStream || RTCPeerConnection.prototype.addTrack) ? true : false;
}

function reloadCameraStream(isOfferer_) {
    loadMyCameraStream();
    loadStrangerCameraStream(isOfferer_);
    addStatusMsg("Attempted to Reload Camera Streams.");
}

function loadMyCameraStream() {
    if (getUserMedia) {
      getUserMedia.call(navigator, { video: {facingMode: "user", aspectRatio: 4 / 3/*height: 272, width: 322*/}, audio: { echoCancellation : true } },
        function(localMediaStream) {
          //Add my video
          $("div#videoBox video#you")[0].muted = true;
          $("div#videoBox video#you")[0].autoplay = true;
          $("div#videoBox video#you").attr('playsinline', '');
          $("div#videoBox video#you").attr('webkit-playsinline', '');
          $("div#videoBox video#you")[0].srcObject = localMediaStream;
          localStream = localMediaStream;
        },
        function(e) {
          addStatusMsg("Your Video has error : " + e);
        }
      );
    } else {
      addStatusMsg("Your browser does not support WebRTC (Camera/Voice chat).");
      return;
    }
}    

function loadStrangerCameraStream(isOfferer_) {
    if(!hasSupportForVideoChat())
      return;
    
    //Only add pending ICE Candidates when getOffer() is finished.
    finishSDPVideoOfferOrAnswer = false;
    iceCandidates = []; //clear ICE Candidates array.
    isOfferer = isOfferer_;
    
    peerConnection = new PeerConnection(rtc_server, rtc_peer_options);
    if (peerConnection.addTrack !== undefined)
      localStream.getTracks().forEach(track => peerConnection.addTrack(track, localStream));
    else
      peerConnection.addStream(localStream);
            
    peerConnection.onicecandidate = function(e) {
      if (!peerConnection || !e || !e.candidate)
        return;    
      
      ws.send(JSON.stringify(['ice_candidate', {"candidate": e.candidate}]));
    };

    if (peerConnection.addTrack !== undefined) {
      //newer technology
      peerConnection.ontrack = function(e) {
        //e.streams.forEach(stream => doAddStream(stream));
        //addStatusMsg("ontrack called");
        //Add stranger video
        $("div#videoBox video#stranger").attr('playsinline', '');
        $("div#videoBox video#stranger").attr('webkit-playsinline', '');
        $('div#videoBox video#stranger')[0].srcObject = e.streams[0];
        $("div#videoBox video#stranger")[0].autoplay = true;
      };
    } else {
      //older technology
      peerConnection.onaddstream = function(e) {
        //addStatusMsg("onaddstream called");
        //Add stranger video
        $("div#videoBox video#stranger").attr('playsinline', '');
        $("div#videoBox video#stranger").attr('webkit-playsinline', '');
        $('div#videoBox video#stranger')[0].srcObject = e.stream;
        $("div#videoBox video#stranger")[0].autoplay = true;
      };
    }
    
    if(isOfferer) {
      peerConnection.createOffer(
        function(offer) {
          peerConnection.setLocalDescription(offer, function () {
            //both offer and peerConnection.localDescription are the same.
            //addStatusMsg('createOffer, localDescription: ' + JSON.stringify(peerConnection.localDescription));
            //addStatusMsg('createOffer, offer: ' + JSON.stringify(offer));
            ws.send(JSON.stringify(['send_offer', {"offer": peerConnection.localDescription}]));
          },
          function(e) {
            addStatusMsg('createOffer, set description error' + e);
          });
        },
        function(e) {
          addStatusMsg("createOffer error: " + e);
        },
        rtc_media_constraints
      );
    }
}

function closeStrangerCameraStream() {
    $('div#videoBox video#stranger')[0].srcObject = null
    if(peerConnection)
      peerConnection.close();
}     
    
function iceCandidate(candidate) {
  //ICE = Interactive Connectivity Establishment
  if(!finishSDPVideoOfferOrAnswer) {
    iceCandidates.push(candidate);
    //addStatusMsg("Queued iceCandidate");
    return;
  }
  
  if(!peerConnection) {
    addStatusMsg("iceCandidate peerConnection not created error.");
    return;
  }
  
  peerConnection.addIceCandidate(new IceCandidate(candidate));
  //addStatusMsg("Added on time, Peer Ice Candidate = " + JSON.stringify(candidate));
}

function getAnswer(answer) {    
    if(!hasSupportForVideoChat())
      return;

    if(!peerConnection) {
      addStatusMsg("getAnswer peerConnection not created error.");
      return;
    }

    peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(new SessionDescription(answer), function() {
      //addStatusMsg("getAnswer SessionDescription answer is ok");
      finishSDPVideoOfferOrAnswer = true;
      while (iceCandidates.length) {
        var candidate = iceCandidates.shift();
        try {
          peerConnection.addIceCandidate(new IceCandidate(candidate));
          //addStatusMsg("Adding queued ICE Candidates");
        } catch(e) {
          addStatusMsg("Error adding queued ICE Candidates error:" + e);
        }
      }
      iceCandidates = [];
    },
    function(e) {
      addStatusMsg("getAnswer SessionDescription fail error: " + e);
    });
}

function getOffer(offer) {
    if(!hasSupportForVideoChat())
      return;
    
    if(!peerConnection) {
      addStatusMsg("getOffer peerConnection not created error.");
      return;
    }
    
    //addStatusMsg("getOffer setRemoteDescription offer: " + JSON.stringify(offer));
    peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(new SessionDescription(offer), function() {
      finishSDPVideoOfferOrAnswer = true;
      while (iceCandidates.length) {
        var candidate = iceCandidates.shift();
        try {
          peerConnection.addIceCandidate(new IceCandidate(candidate));
          //addStatusMsg("Adding queued ICE Candidates");
        } catch(e) {
          addStatusMsg("Error adding queued ICE Candidates error:" + e);
        }
      }
      iceCandidates = [];
      if(!isOfferer) {
        peerConnection.createAnswer(
          function(answer) {
            peerConnection.setLocalDescription(answer);
            //addStatusMsg("getOffer create answer sent: " + JSON.stringify(answer));
            ws.send(JSON.stringify(['send_answer', {"answer": answer}]));
          },
          function(e) {
            addStatusMsg("getOffer setRemoteDescription create answer fail: " + e);
          }
        );
      }
    });
}
```

for serverside I use java server which has this code in Java

```
                    you.videoChatOfferer = true;
                    stranger.videoChatOfferer = false;
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
                    JSONArray list = new JSONArray();
                    list.put("connected");
                    obj.put("videoChatOfferer", you.videoChatOfferer); //first guy offerer for WebRTC.
                    list.put(obj);
                    server.sendMessage(websocket, list.toString()); //connected to chat partner
                    
                    obj = new JSONObject();
                    list = new JSONArray();
                    list.put("connected");
                    obj.put("videoChatOfferer", stranger.videoChatOfferer); //second guy isn't offerer.
                    list.put(obj);
                    server.sendMessage(stranger.getWebSocket(), list.toString()); //connected to chat partner
```

Here is the force command you type in chat which forces the video streams to refresh and works good 90% of the time.

```
        } else if(newMessage.toLowerCase().startsWith("/forcevid")) {
            UserProfile stranger = you.stranger;
            if(stranger == null) {
                obj = new JSONObject();
                list = new JSONArray();

                list.put("gotMessage");
                obj.put("msg", "Couldn't force the video streams as stranger is glitched up");
                list.put(obj);

                sendMessage(websocket, list.toString()); //send message to you
                return;
            }
            if(you.videoChatOfferer) {
                you.videoChatOfferer = false;
                stranger.videoChatOfferer = true;
            } else if(stranger.videoChatOfferer) {
                stranger.videoChatOfferer = false;
                you.videoChatOfferer = true;
            }

            obj = new JSONObject();
            list = new JSONArray();
            list.put("reloadCameraStream");
            obj.put("videoChatOfferer", you.videoChatOfferer); //first guy offerer for WebRTC.
            list.put(obj);
            sendMessage(websocket, list.toString()); //connected to chat partner
            
            obj = new JSONObject();
            list = new JSONArray();
            list.put("reloadCameraStream");
            obj.put("videoChatOfferer", stranger.videoChatOfferer); //second guy isn't offerer.
            list.put(obj);
            sendMessage(stranger.getWebSocket(), list.toString()); //connected to chat partner
        }
```

my packet handler also has this ECHO command for answer / offer

```
public void processPackets(WebSocket websocket, String message) {
    UserProfile you = clients.get(websocket);
    if(you == null) //strange why this happens, but o well.
        return;

    JSONArray packet = new JSONArray(new JSONTokener(message));
    String opcode = (String) packet.get(0);
    opcode = opcode.toLowerCase().trim();
    //System.out.println("PACKET OpCode = " + opcode);

    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray list = new JSONArray();

    switch(opcode) {
       case "ice_candidate":
            JSONObject candidatePackage = (JSONObject) packet.get(1);
            JSONObject candidate = (JSONObject) candidatePackage.get("candidate");

            obj = new JSONObject();
            list = new JSONArray();

            list.put("iceCandidate");
            obj.put("candidate", candidate);
            list.put(obj);

            writeStranger(you, list.toString()); //send ice candidate to stranger

            break;
        case "send_answer":
            JSONObject sendAnswerPackage = (JSONObject) packet.get(1);
            JSONObject answer = (JSONObject) sendAnswerPackage.get("answer");

            obj = new JSONObject();
            list = new JSONArray();

            list.put("getAnswer");
            obj.put("answer", answer);
            list.put(obj);

            writeStranger(you, list.toString()); //send answer to stranger

            break;
        case "send_offer":
            JSONObject offerPackage = (JSONObject) packet.get(1);
            JSONObject offer = (JSONObject) offerPackage.get("offer");

            obj = new JSONObject();
            list = new JSONArray();

            list.put("getOffer");
            obj.put("offer", offer);
            list.put(obj);

            writeStranger(you, list.toString()); //send ice candidate to stranger

            break;
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the browser developer tools console?

Comment: @Jaromanda X No errors it even works sometimes. there is errors for  addTrack and forEach on older browsers but thats not that important i think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason of this race condition seems to be the missing sequence dependency between **loadMyCameraStream** and **loadStrangerCameraStream**. You may try to call **loadStrangerCameraStream** within **loadMyCameraStream**;

```
 getUserMedia.call(navigator, { video: {facingMode: "user", aspectRatio: 4 / 3/*height: 272, width: 322*/}, audio: { echoCancellation : true } },
        function(localMediaStream) {
          //Add my video
          $("div#videoBox video#you")[0].muted = true;
          $("div#videoBox video#you")[0].autoplay = true;
          $("div#videoBox video#you").attr('playsinline', '');
          $("div#videoBox video#you").attr('webkit-playsinline', '');
          $("div#videoBox video#you")[0].srcObject = localMediaStream;
          localStream = localMediaStream;
          loadStrangerCameraStream(isOfferer_); // <-- from here
        },
```

For a minimalistic working example which has a similar flow with yours, you may check the following code;

https://github.com/kaplanke/tamed-chat-client/blob/master/test/standalone_client.html

Comment: Thanks I did a big overhaul on the site and I think I finally have fixed it the problem was the peerConnection wasn't fully established before incoming offer and answer was given and the localstream webcam feed also had the problem like you mentioned it gets callback and while its getting this callback it's already processing the stranger camera connection so I wrapped everything up in `setInterval(function() {}, 10);` and problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

New Code fixed problem

```
    function loadStrangerCameraStream(isOfferer_) {
    if(!hasSupportForVideoChat())
      return;
    
    var gotlocalStream = setInterval(function() {
      if(!localStream) return;
      
      /*
      const videoTracks = localStream.getVideoTracks();
  const audioTracks = localStream.getAudioTracks();
  if (videoTracks.length > 0) {
      addStatusMsg(`Using video device: ${videoTracks[0].label}`);
  }
  if (audioTracks.length > 0) {
      addStatusMsg(`Using audio device: ${audioTracks[0].label}`);
  }*/

      //Only add pending ICE Candidates when getOffer() is finished.
      finishSDPVideoOfferOrAnswer = false;
      iceCandidates = []; //clear ICE Candidates array.
      isOfferer = isOfferer_;
    
      peerConnection = new PeerConnection(rtc_server, rtc_peer_options);
        
      //Peer Connection
      peerConnection.onicecandidate = function(e) {
        if (!peerConnection || !e || !e.candidate)
          return;
        peerConnection.addIceCandidate(new IceCandidate(e.candidate));
        ws.send(JSON.stringify(['ice_candidate', {"candidate": e.candidate}]));
      };
      
      if (peerConnection.addTrack !== undefined)
        localStream.getTracks().forEach(track => peerConnection.addTrack(track, localStream));
      else
        peerConnection.addStream(localStream);
      
      if (peerConnection.addTrack !== undefined) {
        //newer technology
        peerConnection.ontrack = function(e) {
          //addStatusMsg("ontrack called");
          //Add stranger video
          $("div#videoBox video#stranger").attr('playsinline', '');
          $("div#videoBox video#stranger").attr('webkit-playsinline', '');
          $('div#videoBox video#stranger')[0].srcObject = e.streams[0];
          $("div#videoBox video#stranger")[0].autoplay = true;
        };
      } else {
        //older technology
        peerConnection.onaddstream = function(e) {
          //addStatusMsg("onaddstream called");
          //Add stranger video
          $("div#videoBox video#stranger").attr('playsinline', '');
          $("div#videoBox video#stranger").attr('webkit-playsinline', '');
          $('div#videoBox video#stranger')[0].srcObject = e.stream;
          $("div#videoBox video#stranger")[0].autoplay = true;
        };
      }
      
      if(isOfferer) {
        peerConnection.createOffer(
          function(offer) {
            peerConnection.setLocalDescription(offer, function () {
              //both offer and peerConnection.localDescription are the same.
              //addStatusMsg('createOffer, localDescription: ' + JSON.stringify(peerConnection.localDescription));
              //addStatusMsg('createOffer, offer: ' + JSON.stringify(offer));
              ws.send(JSON.stringify(['send_offer', {"offer": offer}]));
            },
            function(e) {
              addStatusMsg('createOffer, peerConnection set description error' + e);
            });
          },
          function(e) {
            addStatusMsg("createOffer error: " + e);
          },
          rtc_media_constraints
        );
      }
      
      clearInterval(gotlocalStream);
  }, 10);    
}

function closeStrangerCameraStream() {
    $('div#videoBox video#stranger')[0].srcObject = null
    if(peerConnection)
      peerConnection.close();
}     
    
function iceCandidate(candidate) {
  //ICE = Interactive Connectivity Establishment
  if(!finishSDPVideoOfferOrAnswer) {
    iceCandidates.push(candidate);
    //addStatusMsg("Queued iceCandidate");
    return;
  }
  
  if(!peerConnection) {
    addStatusMsg("iceCandidate peerConnection not created error.");
    return;
  }
  
  peerConnection.addIceCandidate(new IceCandidate(candidate));
  //addStatusMsg("Added on time, Peer Ice Candidate = " + JSON.stringify(candidate));
}

function getAnswer(answer) {    
  if(!hasSupportForVideoChat())
    return;

  var gotPeerConnection = setInterval(function() {
    if(!peerConnection) return;
    
    if(!peerConnection) {
      addStatusMsg("getAnswer peerConnection not created error.");
      return;
    }
        
//set remote peer connection.
    peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(new SessionDescription(answer), function() {
      //addStatusMsg("getAnswer SessionDescription answer is ok");
      finishSDPVideoOfferOrAnswer = true;
      while (iceCandidates.length) {
        var candidate = iceCandidates.shift();
        try {
          peerConnection.addIceCandidate(new IceCandidate(candidate));
          //addStatusMsg("Adding queued ICE Candidates");
        } catch(e) {
          addStatusMsg("Error adding queued ICE Candidates error:" + e);
        }
      }
      iceCandidates = [];
    },
    function(e) {
      addStatusMsg("getAnswer peerConnection SessionDescription fail error: " + e);
    });
    clearInterval(gotPeerConnection);
  }, 10);  
}

function getOffer(offer) {
  if(!hasSupportForVideoChat())
    return;
  var gotPeerConnection = setInterval(function() {
    if(!peerConnection) return;
      
    if(!peerConnection) {
      addStatusMsg("getOffer peerConnection not created error.");
      return;
    }
    
    //addStatusMsg("getOffer setRemoteDescription offer: " + JSON.stringify(offer));    
    peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(new SessionDescription(offer), function() {
      finishSDPVideoOfferOrAnswer = true;
      while (iceCandidates.length) {
        var candidate = iceCandidates.shift();
        try {
          peerConnection.addIceCandidate(new IceCandidate(candidate));
          //addStatusMsg("Adding queued ICE Candidates");
        } catch(e) {
          addStatusMsg("Error adding queued ICE Candidates error:" + e);
        }
      }
      iceCandidates = [];
      if(!isOfferer) {
        peerConnection.createAnswer(
          function(answer) {
            peerConnection.setLocalDescription(answer);
            //addStatusMsg("getOffer create answer sent: " + JSON.stringify(answer));
            ws.send(JSON.stringify(['send_answer', {"answer": answer}]));
          },
          function(e) {
            addStatusMsg("createAnswer peerConnection create answer fail: " + e);
          }
        );
      }
    });
    clearInterval(gotPeerConnection);
  }, 10); 
}
```